# How to test Click outside directive in angular?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-directives, angular-test

I want to test click-outside directive. The extension is i a ignoring a div element while clicking outside.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from 
'@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

@Output()
public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<HTMLElement>();

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
public onClick(targetElement: HTMLElement) {
    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    const doctorDropdown = document.getElementById('doctor-dropdown-list');
    if (!clickedInside && !doctorDropdown.contains(targetElement)) {
        this.clickOutside.emit(targetElement);
    }
}
```

}

I am not able to test this part !

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
public onClick(targetElement: HTMLElement) {
    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    const doctorDropdown = document.getElementById('doctor-dropdown-list');
    if (!clickedInside && !doctorDropdown.contains(targetElement)) {
        this.clickOutside.emit(targetElement);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ClickOutsideDirective } from '../click-outside.directive';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    template: `
    <div class="inside" (clickOutside)="clickOutside()"></div> // or doctor-dropdown-list
    <div class="outside"></div>
  `
})
class TestComponent {
    clickOutside(): void{}
}

describe('ClickOutsideDirective', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let component: TestComponent;
    let element: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ClickOutsideDirective, TestComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should create directive', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should trigger click inside', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'clickOutside');    
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const inside = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.inside')).nativeElement;
        inside.click();

        expect(component.clickOutside).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    it('should trigger click outside', () => {
        spyOn(component, 'clickOutside');
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const outside = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.outside')).nativeElement;
        outside.click();

        expect(component.clickOutside).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.